# How to Add BUTTON WITH DROPDOWN OPTIONS in Angular 4 datatables when fetching data from Object KeyValue pair from Typrescript File

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

I want to add a button with drop-down options in a datatable row in Angular 4. I am using ngFor to get values of table head and row, which I have defined in Typescript file as Array of the object and set to Typescript property.Getting the table data perfectly, but I need a a button with dropdown and wondering how I can achieve this in the object array.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
**************************
HTML
***************************

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <th *ngFor="let colValues of tableData | columnPipe ">{{colValues}}</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let row of tableData | searchPipe : mysearchFilter.value">
<td *ngFor="let rowValues of row | rowPipe">{{ rowValues }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


**************************
App.ts
***************************

export class JobComponent implements OnInit {         
public tableData: any = [
{ 'ShipmentRef': 'E159 025 035', 'CustomerName' : 'Sample Pty Ltd', 'PickupSuburb' : 'Lynwood WA 6147', 'DeliverySuburb' : 'Rockingham WA 6219' , 'JobType' : 'Domestic', 'Weight' : '40 Kg', 'DispatchStatus': 'Dispatched', 'AccountType': 'Credit', 'Hold': ' ' , 'Managed By': 'Third Party', 'TrackingStatus': 'Track Here', 'Action': ''}
];
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
}

    **************************
    pipes.ts
    ***************************
export class columnPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const columnNames = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      for (const key in value[i]) {
        if (columnNames.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          columnNames.push(key);
        }
      }
    }
    return columnNames;
  }
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'rowPipe'
})

export class rowPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const rowValues = Object.keys(value);
    return rowValues.map(k => value[k]);
  }
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe'
})
export class searchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: any[], filter: string): any {
    if (!values || !values.length) return [];
    if (!filter) return values;

    filter = filter.toUpperCase();

    if (filter && Array.isArray(values)) {
      const keys = Object.keys(values[0]);
      return values.filter(v => v && keys.some(k => v[k].toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Native dropdowns for Angular apps simply use the html `select` tag. You put the `*ngFor` on the `option` tag to loop through the data. This creates an option for each object in your tableData array (you only have 1).

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="Value">
  <option *ngFor="let value of tableData" [value]="value.ShipmentRef">{{value.CustomerName}}</option>
</select>
```

You can set the option display to anything the user would recognize, here I made it the CustomerName. `[value]` usually selects an id in the data that uniquely identifies each row, but here I set it to ShipmentRef. `[(ngModel)]` here binds the user's selection to a variable that needs to exist in your TypeScript.

Add something like: `selectedValue: string = null;` under your `tableData` instantiation. Then, when the user selects an option, the variable will contain the value and you can use it other places (e.g. to highlight the associated data in your html table).